# how to animate label or uiview like swing

Tags: iphone, ipad

how to animate animate UIView or UILable like swing

```
CGPoint newLeftCenter = CGPointMake( 00.0f + label.frame.size.width / 2.0f, label.center.y);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
label.center = newLeftCenter;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will animate from left to right!

i need to animate from right to left too!

so when my action trigger it UIVIew or label need to move from left to right and right to left.

@thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to add two sequential animations you could do the following by using `setAnimationDidStopSelector`

```
- (void) animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID 
                 finished:(NSNumber *)finished 
                  context:(void *)context
{
    CGPoint newRightCenter = CGPointMake( 00.0f + label.frame.size.width * 2, label.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    label.center = newRightCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}

- (void) doAnimation
{
    CGPoint newLeftCenter = CGPointMake( 00.0f + label.frame.size.width / 2.0f, label.center.y);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    label.center = newLeftCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Comment: @ OmarAbdelhafith Thanks its worked for me but animation is moving fast! when it animated from left to right and after that its moving from right to left its animating fast! [or moving fast]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the animation autoreverse to YES.

```
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
```

From Apple documents:

```
If you enable autoreversing, a single animation cycle changes the properties being animated to their new values and then back to their original values. At the end of the animations, the affected views are then updated immediately to reflect the new values. This method does nothing if called from outside of an animation block. By default, autoreversing is disabled.

If you combine autoreversing with a repeat count (settable using the setAnimationRepeatCount: method), you can create animations that shift back and forth between the old and new values the specified number of times. However, remember that the repeat count indicates the number of complete cycles. If you specify an integral value such as 2.0, the animation ends on the old value, which is followed by the view immediately updating itself to show the new value, which might be jarring. If you want the animation to end on the new value (instead of the old value), add 0.5 to the repeat count value. This adds an extra half cycle to the animation.

Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. Instead, you should use theanimateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: method to specify your animations and the animation options.
```